# Glyphicon Search on button not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm new to doing front end design but I'm learning it so that I can apply simple designs to my projects. I'm using **Bootstrap 3.3.7** and had no problems with the icons except when I tried to add `"glyphicon glyphicon-search"`icon.

I did some research but I noticed that most results suggest that I do,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
</button>
```

Unfortunately, it still won't display the search icon. Please help me resolve this.

I only get a blank button with no icon next to my search text field.

[image]

Comment: Any error in console??

Comment: Its working fine, [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbq4z4a/)

Comment: @Manu, I have the bootstrap zip file extracted. I just figured out the problem. The fonts files were not imported to the project. When you asked about the error, I did some code inspection and found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of helping others who are new and might encounter this, here's how I solved it.

If you downloaded the zipped file of bootstrap online and extracted it, you'll get 3 folders.

```
css
fonts
js
```

Don't forget to include the contents of each folder to their respective destination folders in your projects. Like what's shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The files under fonts folder prepended by `glyphicons-halflings...` are needed to display icons.

I didn't paste these fonts files when I created the project which caused missing search icon.

I hope this will help.